# Where do Canada geese live at night?

Tags: birds, bird-behaviour, geese

I live in the central Ohio area. There is a human-made lake surrounded by grasses around my home, and the size of the lake is about 2 tennis courts. Many Canada Geese together with their chicks gather around this area in the morning and hang out.

Around sunset (around 8:50 pm currently), they walk together to a direction away from the lake and disappear. By counting the number of chicks, I can determine some Canada geese come around every day. So come and go are their daily routines.

However, I don't know where are they heading to or where do they live in the evening. The direction they go to has several small buildings and sideways surrounded by grasses, and will be segregated by traffics farther away, so there does not seem to exist a better environment than the lake area.

Does anyone know where geese live during the night? Why don't they stay around the lake?

Comment: "size of the lake is about 2 tennis courts" - that's a pond.

Comment: @whatsisname That's a better word. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ducks and geese mostly sleep on the water, though occasionally you'll see some sleeping on the shore. Being on the water keeps them safe from landbound predators while they sleep.

If they're not staying on your local pond, perhaps there's a larger lake nearby that they're heading to overnight.